# Python & regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Hi i'm making a program that will take a command such as `!math(5+5)` from skype and return the result, i'm having trouble getting the regex expression right, I have been reading the docs and I just can't get it right.

I am trying to support all operators, so *, ** /, +, -, %, and **. the trouble comes when I try to use **, either I use one regex and lose the option for exponents or have the exponent only option.

Here's my expression:

```
expr = re.search(r'((\d+)(\s*.?|.*\**)(\d+))', 'math(500**1000)')
```

And then i'm parsing it using groups,

```
build_expr = {
    'number1': int(expr.group(2)),
    'operator': expr.group(3),
    'number2': int(expr.group(4))
}
```

results for giving the reseach module the argument with exponents:

```
>>> expr.group()
'500**1000'
>>> expr.group(1)
'500**1000'
>>> expr.group(2)
'500'
>>> expr.group(3)
'**100'
```

And it works just fine and dandy with 1 character strings, such as `math(500+1000)`

```
>>> expr.group(1)
'500+1000'
>>> expr.group(2)
'500'
>>> expr.group(3)
'+'
>>> expr.group(4)
'1000'
```

Here's the entire function

```
def math_func(expr_arg):
    expr = re.search(r'((\d+)(\s*.?|.*\**)(\d+))', expr_arg)
    #parse_expr = ' '.join(expr.group()).split()


    build_expr = {
        'number1': int(expr.group(2)),
        'operator': expr.group(3),
        'number2': int(expr.group(4))
    }

    if build_expr['operator'] == '+':
        operation = build_expr['number1'] + build_expr['number2']
        return str(operation)
    elif build_expr['operator'] == '-':
        operation = build_expr['number1'] - build_expr['number2']
        return str(operation)
    elif build_expr['operator'] == '/':
        operation = build_expr['number1'] / build_expr['number2']
        return str(operation)
    elif build_expr['operator'] == '%':
        operation = build_expr['number1'] % build_expr['number2']
        return str(operation)
    elif build_expr['operator'] == '*':
        operation = build_expr['number1'] * build_expr['number2']
        return str(operation)
    elif build_expr['operator'] == '**':
        operation = build_expr['number1'] ** build_expr['number2']
        return str(operation)
    else:
        return 'Invalid operator'
    return 'shes all good son'

f = math_func('math(500+1000)')
Message.Chat.SendMessage('>> ' + f)
```

Comment: What is `.*\**` supposed to match?

Comment: (\s*.?|.*\**) was suppose to match any 1 letter string or the string '**'

Comment: It seems you are building a parser. Are you sure you want to go with regular expressions? If you want to support complex (i.e. non-regular) operations such as `1+2*3`, regular expressions will block you.

Comment: what would you suggest for complex expressions

Comment: google "shunting-yard algorithm", pick a link :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be matched using:

```
(\d+)\s*([-+*/%]+)\s*(\d+)
```

Breakdown:

- `(\d+)` will match one or more digits
- `\s*` will match the whitespaces, if there's any
- `([-+*/%]+)` will match one or more *operator* characters

Comment: thanks how'd you figure that out - wait nvm it's busted

Comment: nevermind it works, just this skype API is atrocious

Comment: nvm turns out its me whos atrocious :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about just using:

```
(\d+)\s*(\*\*|[+/%*-])\s*(\d+)
```

`[+/%*-]` means "one character, one from the list inside brackets".

No need to wrap everything inside a capturing group, the whole match is already stored in `group(0)`.

I'm not sure how you got to `.*\**` so I can't tell you what's your mistake is here, but the new regex should [do the job](http://regex101.com/r/jN2gD1).

Comment: yea i'm not quite sure either soon as you asked me that i had trouble coming up with a response

Comment: @jeff "Who wrote this weird piece of code? Oh... Me." Happened to all of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have trusted data, you could just replace your `math_func` with `eval` and be done with it.